# Eclipse is saying "Missing builder" and there's no way to configure it

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant

I'm trying to configure my projects to build with jdk 1.6. The problem is that when I removed 1.7 from my computer, my projects show up as having "Missing builder (org.eclipse.vjet.eclipse.core.builder). And trying to build them shows "The specified JRE does not exist"

There's no option to configure which JRE to use in the builders, when I select the one that says missing, "Edit" is greyed out.

How can I fix this so my project can build?

Stack Overflow won't let me post images directly, so here are the links to them, as hosted on imgur.com:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Missing Builder comes from not having VJet installed.  You can disable or remove the reference to it from the shown Property Page, or just install VJet. The other you might resolve by going to the `Installed JREs` preference page and making sure all of the values are correct, and then fixing any existing launch configurations (`Run`->`Run Configurations...`) that may be pointing to JREs that aren't around any more (such as by changing them to use an *Execution Environment* instead of a specific JRE by name).

Comment: I only had to do the second part of what you said, and then it started working. I guess VJet wasn't needed to build. Thanks